# Video decoder initialization failed on android WebView in android TCL TV

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an android app installed on TCL tv that use Webview to display a sequence of videos (H264 formatted), same app work on Samsung tv and display all videos in the sequence perfectly, somehow on TCL TV I got
`{"video decoder initialization failed"}` randomly on some videos from the sequence :
all the videos are the same formated (**The same video sometimes works and sometimes does not**):
I have been checked chromium supported format and I see that it's working fine on other TVs.

Has anyone ever encountered this??